# verticalGap in flex 4.5 with Vgroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I am migrating my **flex 3** application to **flex 4.5**. So, I want to replace my `mx.containers.VBox` component in **Flex 3** to a `spark.components.Vgroup` component.

I have the `verticalGap` property, which is important for design, it should be assigned in `Vgoup` but it doesn't defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution !

It's just change the `verticalGap` in `VGoup` or `HorizontalGap` in the `HGroup` by `gap`

Notice : in this case, gap is not a style css.