# horizontalGap Group

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I use `horizontalGap` in the HGroup in **Flex 4.5**?
This function doesn't exist in the **flex 4.5** like **flex 3**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [verticalGap in flex 4.5 with Vgroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559541/verticalgap-in-flex-4-5-with-vgroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `gap` property. If you're working with a `Group` instead, the property is on the layout object for the group.